# how to extract one element from nested list as vector - R twitteR package

Tags: r, list, twitter

I have a nested list of 'twitteR' user objects, whereby the 1st level of the list is a given user-id, e.g. `000000000`, and the second level is a number of attributes for that entry, e.g. `description` or `name`. There are n list elements, and for each of these elements, the exact same variables/attributes exist.

What I want to do, is to extract **one** particular attribute/variable for every 1st order element of the list and save it to a character vector.

I can do this with a for loop, but this takes forever, and I'd really like for it to be more efficient, as I want to extract these variables for a huge amount of similar lists.

So, this is what the data i have looks like at the moment, let's assume my list is called `list`:

```
> list$`00000000`$description
[1] "bla bla bla bla"
> list$`00000001`$description
[1] "blub blub blub"
> list$`00000002`$description
[1] "pim pim pim"
```

and this is what i'd like to have

```
> description
[1] "bla bla bla bla" "blub blub blub" "pim pim pim"
> class(description)
[1] "character"
```

Is there a way of elegantly doing this in as few lines as possible, without the need for a for-loop? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please `dput` your example to reproduce it and the expected output?

Comment: This type of processing is automated in the [rtweet](http://rtweet.info) package, which [you should now be using instead of `twitteR` anyway](http://lists.hexdump.org/pipermail/twitter-users-hexdump.org/2016-August/000050.html). Also, can you also specify "huge amount"? If under 10 million, for instance, then most machines can handle this relatively quickly without having to get too creative.

Comment: thanks for this reply @mkearney - eventually, i'm looking to scale this to +10 million. efficiency is key. how exactly is this done in rtweet? i'm just familiarising myself with this package now, having read your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Using the rlist library, you can use functions like select or filter on lists:

```
library(rlist)
# Sample data
twitterers <- list("0" = list(descr = "bla", other = 11), "1" = list(descr = "blu", other = 20))
# list.select returns a list, so you unlist it and convert it to a vector to have the desired output
as.vector(unlist(list.select(twitterers, descr)))
```

Result:

```
[1] "bla" "blu"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer using only `base`.

**Data**

```
list<-structure(list(`00000000` = structure(list(description = "bla bla bla bla"), .Names = "description", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame"), `00000001` = structure(list(description = "blub blub blub"), .Names = "description", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame"), `00000002` = structure(list(description = "pim pim pim"), .Names = "description", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("00000000", "00000001", 
"00000002"))
```

**Solution**

```
sapply(list,function(x){x$description})
```

This returns an object of class `character`.